# Is there a performance boost in converting array items to variables and back?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, variables

I have a huge array of RSS feeds and want to run a bunch of functions over the description text to clean it up. I have something similar to this:

```
  $j=0;                                                         
  foreach($feed as $item){
    $feed[$j]['description'] = (do something here);
    $feed[$j]['description'] = (do something here);
    $feed[$j]['description'] = (do something here);
    $feed[$j]['description'] = (do something here);
    $feed[$j]['description'] = (do something here);
  $j++;
  }
```

(I've kept it as a list of separate functions as the full code has a bunch of conditionals in there)

Is there any performance gain converting the `$feed[$j]['description']` to a variable first? Eg:

```
  $j=0;                                                         
  foreach($feed as $item){
    $f = $feed[$j]['description'];
    $f = (do something here);
    $f = (do something here);
    $f = (do something here);
    $f = (do something here);
    $f = (do something here);
    $feed[$j]['description'] = $f;
  $j++;
  }
```

Basically, is `$feed[$j]['description']` treated the same as if it was a variable, or is it constantly having to be re-looked up each time a function runs?

Comment: `$item['description']` you don't need to use `$j` if you're using a `foreach`

Comment: @Prix I use `$j` because I've found in the past that updating `$item['description']` within a foreach loop, doesn't have the permanent affect outside of the loop's scope that `$feed[$j]['description']` has. Unrelated, but maybe I'm missing a core concept there...

Comment: Then use a `for` and read the original array 1 by 1 instead of having it all load on the `foreach`. `for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($feed); $j++)`

Comment: @Prix I always assumed `for($j = 0; $j < count($feed); $j++)` then assigning `$feed[$j]['description']` was basically the same thing, just different syntax. Is iterating through the array in a `for` vs `foreach` better for memory or for speed?

Comment: Memory and probably speed you would have to benchmark yourself as it will depend on the amount and data you're dealing with in most cases the speed gain will be insignificant and in some cases it may be huge.

Comment: @Prix Thanks for the info. If `for` is superior to `foreach`, is there any reason why I shouldn't rip out every `foreach` I've ever used and replace it with a `for`? Why would a `foreach` ever be useful then?

Comment: It depends on how and at what you're using it at like I previously said and you can easily benchmark both by using `microtime` function.

Comment: @Prix Also, doesn't the `for` simply say "count from 0 to the total number of members in the array"? That only seems to determine the indexed number `$j` and has no baring on loading only 1 array item at at time. If I then do the same `$feed[$j]['description']` within it, how is this influencing a 1 by 1 array read? Functionally wise, it seems the same as the `foreach` to me...

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: @Shomz I'm not denying it works, I'm simply trying to understand why it would work like that, when it appears to be saying something else.

Comment: I'm not saying you're denying it - I'm just suggesting you test it yourself: measure the time for the first method (do **a lot** more iterations for both), then measure the time for the second and compare the results.

Comment: @Shomz I'll test it now, but trust it will work. Any explanation on the syntax? How does it know to slice that specific array up into 1x1's if the array isn't referenced in the `for` (besides establishing a max count #)? If I put 10 different arrays in there, are they all going to get sliced into 1x1's?